# i want execute bash on server side with php

Tags: php, apache, exec

I want to execute bash script with php.
When i launch php script in browser i got an error " permission denied"

when i run php whoami , i get www-data. I granted all permisions for write and read.
When i run bash script as www-data it works. But via php im still getting the same error.Should i check php.ini settings or somethnig?

If i write unknown bash command in php script, using shell_exec(). I got an error sh: command not found.I think it should be "bash: comand not found".

Can u please help me out.

```
PHP
<?php
      $message=shell_exec ("bash bashscript 2>&1");
      print_r($message);
    ?>
```

bash

```
#!bin/bash
cp /myfiles/file aa
```

Comment: Give it executable permissions?

Comment: Ive made it!. I have to change php. ini file.  In ini file i found Disabled functions, exec function was inside. I deleted it and restarted apache. Now it works